# How to fix invalid ReSharper view of test names?

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper

Im using NUnit (3.8.1)  with Resharper (2018.2.3) like this:

```
    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetTests()
    {
        yield return T("foo.bA..r@gmail.com", "foobar@gmail.com");
        yield return T("foo.bA..r@example.com", "foo.ba..r@example.com");
        yield return T("user.name+tag+sorting@example.com", "user.name@example.com");
        yield return T("admin@mailserver1", "admin@mailserver1");
        yield return T("aaaafoo.bA..r@gmail.com", "aaafoobar@gmail.com");
    }

    private static TestCaseData T(string input, string output)
    {
        return new TestCaseData(input, output)
               {
                   TestName = string.Format("'{0}' => '{1}'", input, output)
               };
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTests))]
    public void Normalize(string input, string output)
    {
        //some test here
    }
```

But when I run my tests, in Resharper window, I see my names cropped by some mystical logic:

[image: invalid resharper test view]

What is causing my names to become like this? How to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by *in Resharper window*? something from under `ReSharper -> Windows` from the tool bar?

Comment: I couldn't find any proof, but I suspect there is some logic which split the full test (including name space and class) name by `.` to show the simplified name.

Comment: I mean window which open when you run tests by default. It is showing those cropped strings instead of correct ones.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, I don't have any window getting opened when I run tests.

Comment: "Unit test sessions" window. Resharper => Unit tests => Unit test sessions

Comment: Interesting, I just did it myself and the result is as you expected. One difference, I'm using `NUnit 2` and used `return new TestCaseData(input, output).SetName(string.Format("'{0}' => '{1}'", input, output));`, but I don't think it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like ReSharper is having issues with dots in test case names when it's running NUnit parameterized tests: it simply discards whatever precedes a dot.

There's no such problem with ReSharper running xUnit theories, for example, nor does NUnit's console runner seem to return anything weird that would seem to have an effect on ReSharper behavior.

What you can do to work around this issue is provide a descriptive name for each test case using the `SetName()` method, like this:

```
 private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetTests()
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData("foo.bA..r@gmail.com", "foobar@gmail.com").SetName("GMail: dots removed, casing normalized to lower (1)");
        yield return new TestCaseData("foo.bA..r@example.com", "foo.ba..r@example.com").SetName("Example domain: dots intact, casing normalized to lower");
        yield return new TestCaseData("user.name+tag+sorting@example.com", "user.name@example.com").SetName("Example domain: local part stripped from + and everything that follows");
        yield return new TestCaseData("admin@mailserver1", "admin@mailserver1").SetName("Whatever you're checking here");
        yield return new TestCaseData("aaaafoo.bA..r@gmail.com", "aaafoobar@gmail.com").SetName("GMail: dots removed, casing normalized to lower (2)");
    }
```

As long as you're not using dots in the names, you should be fine:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you for pointing this out! You might as well create bug ticket on their bug tracker. Thanks!